# WIFI : "No adapter found" in newly installed ubuntu 20.04 linux

Tags: drivers, wireless

I tried to update my wireless adapter from Software Update and additional hardware update but failed and taking hints from  browsers I tried to fix it from synaptic program manager by reinstalling iwlwifi and many stuff similar to it and again it didn't work. And lastly tried from terminal by taking hints from you tube to install or updates it but it ask username and password for GitHub and I tried after making account and shifting it to terminal but again same problem. These are my wireless adapter details:

```
Network controller:Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 
DEVICE NAME :TIFFANY
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11/g/n PCIe Adapter [10ec:d723]
   Kernal modules: rtwpci
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Hello! sir I have add all those outputs .

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to install the driver. Disable Secure Boot in BIOS and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Comment: It run very well, but still the condition is same.

Comment: This comment doesn't give any information. Did everything install correctly?

Comment: yes sir everything install correctly but still the same problem? I have to do reboot or something else?

Comment: Correct, reboot after you installed the driver.

Comment: Sir now it stucks showing ubuntu logo without buffering and and mute activate in keyboard. I left it for half an hour and still not opening.